# unable to validate datetime field

Tags: django, datetime, django-forms

I'm unable to validate `datetime` field. Is there something I missed?

```
from django import forms
class A(forms.Form):
    a = forms.DateTimeField(widget=forms.DateTimeInput(format=('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M')))

data = {'a':"2007-03-04T21:08"}

a = A(data)

print a.is_valid()
   -> False

print a.errors
   -> {'a': [u'Enter a valid date/time.']}
```

---

solution:

```
class A(forms.Form):
        a = forms.DateTimeField(input_formats=['%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've specified the `format` parameter to the widget, which describes how the existing value should be displayed. You need to provide the `input_formats` parameter to the field itself, which determines how the data is accepted.